# Most recent TIMESTAMP joining the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, max

I have a table with columns: START POINT, END POINT, START DATE, END DATE,RIDE NUMBER
I need to receive all records from it, and **END POINT, STARTE DAT, END DATE** for most recent record (start date) which is from the same start point.

Example:

1. Start point - A, end point - B, start date 1/1/1 10:30, end date 1/1/1 10:35
2. Start point - A, end point - C, start date 1/1/1 10:20, end date 1/1/1 10:35
3. Start point - A, end point - B, start date 1/1/1 10:25, end date 1/1/1 10:35
4. Start point - A, end point - D, start date 1/1/1 10:27, end date 1/1/1 10:35

So I need to receive last ride (**START DATE**, end date does not matter ) from the **same START POINT**t (in the example it's A, end point does not matter) for every record.

So for **ride 1**  I should get **ride 4**. For **2** I should get **nothing** (it's the last ride), for **3** I should get record **2** and for record **4** I should get record **3**.  And so on.

The problem is there is many start points, and many start dates.

I was trying to join same table with start dates condition using MAX function (that start date from first trip < maX(start date from last trip), but it's not working.

Do you have an idea how to join it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below should do the job. However if there are more than one records for the same startedate both records will be returned. You might have to decide to pick either one by picking min rowid or max rowid.

```
 Select 
    a.STARTPOINT,a.ENDPOINT, a.STARTDATE, a.ENDDATE,a.RIDENUMBER,recentride.ENDPOINT,recentride.STARTEDATE,recentride.ENDDATE
    from ridetable a,ridetable recentride
    where a.startpoint = recentride.startpoint 
    and  recentride.startedate < a.STARTEDATE
    and  recentride.startedate = (select max(c.STARTEDATE) 
                                  from ridetable c
                                  where c.startpoint = a.startpoint
                                  and c.startedate < a.STARTEDATE)
```

Comment: Hey, it seems to be working. thank you very much, but can I just explain me why did you define third table ridetable? I was doing in same way, but I was trying with (select max(recentride.startdate)...), I guess that was my mistake.

Comment: This is just one way of doing it, 3rd table is to find the max value less than current record.If this query helped you kindly mark and upvote the answer.